# Glassfish 3.1 Remote client connecting to JMS queue in cluster

Tags: glassfish, jms, cluster-computing, glassfish-3

Glassfish 3.1.2
Ubuntu 12.04

I've created a cluster of two nodes and have a JMS queue.
I'm having issues trying to connect to this JMS queue using a remote standalone client.
The cluster JMS listener is on port 27676 and the queue is deployed to the cluster.

mq://Glassfish2:27676/,mq://Glassfish3:27676

When I connect using the code I'd use to connect to a stand alone instance the message is not received by the cluster.
I believe it is using the default 7676 port. When the IIOP port is changed to use port 23700 which is the one the cluster (DAS) is using I get a connection refused exception as it is trying to connect to localhost:27676. At least it's the right port.

WARNING: [C4003]: Error occurred on connection creation [localhost:27676]. - cause: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect

I've also updated the following values in node config file (domain.xml) to remove references to localhost. jms-host and node-host values.

I had this issue before with a stand alone instance and it was resolved by adding entries to the /etc/hosts file. However, this does not seem to resolve the issue. 
I also have all server instance IPs in the hosts file.

Am I missing something very basic here?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you look log files under

> ${glassfish_home}/glassfish/nodes/cluster-name/instance-name/imq/instances/instance-name/log

folder, you will see that

### **master brockers does not match**

Every your node has different master brockers, probably **every node know its own brocker as master brocker..**

I had the same error and after a few days find this..